How do i fix Easy Apache Repository error on Cent OS
My VPS is using Cent OS7 with cPanel 110.
Since July 1, Cent OS7 reached its EOL but i couldnt upgrade due to some web applications running older PHP versions and since then I have been having issues with Easy Apache4.


Error: “/usr/local/cpanel/bin/python-packman” reported error code “1” when it ended: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/packman_get_info_json", line 16, in packman.init_yum() File "/usr/local/cpanel/bin/packman_lib/yum_impl.py", line 78, in init_yum yb.repos.populateSack() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 347, in populateSack self.doSetup() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 157, in doSetup self.retrieveAllMD() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 88, in retrieveAllMD dl = repo._async and repo._commonLoadRepoXML(repo) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1482, in _commonLoadRepoXML result = self._getFileRepoXML(local, text) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1259, in _getFileRepoXML size=102400) # setting max size as 100K File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1042, in _getFile raise e yum.Errors.NoMoreMirrorsRepoError: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try. http://asi-fs-l.contabo.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found w/ /usr/local/cpanel/bin/packman_get_info_json ea-php71-php-fpm Often errors like this can be resolved by running `yum makecache` 



I have tried running "yum makecache" but its returning same error.
I am still working on upgrading the web applications to higher PHP version and just need more time before doing an OS upgrade.
I reached out to my Host but was replied that they are no longer supporting Cent OS7 and its an unmanaged server.
Is there anyway for me to fix this issue annd make Easy Apache4 work again because as it is, I'm unable  to change PHP versions
Thanks

Here is how I fixed the issue: I see that On July 1st, 2024 CentOS 7 is End of Life and the CentOS team has removed their mirrors so will be the same for "asi-fs-l.contabo.net" as well. These are the steps I followed:

Open the file /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
[cdr@ ~]# nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo


Then, in that file, replace asi-fs-l.contabo.net with vault.centos.org

yum clean all && yum makecache


This solved the issue for me; this informations based on https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/24571139547415-Could-not-retrieve-mirrorlist-http-mirrorlist-centos-org-on-CentOS-7
